# splitting list and storing contents in an another array

Tags: c#

I receive the following list of strings from client. It is dynamic in its nature and can has less element than showing below.

```
0: "5146d57a-701d-e511-82ee-303a64efb676_6544d57a-701d-e511-82ee-303a64efb676"

1: "5146d57a-701d-e511-82ee-303a64efb676_6644d57a-701d-e511-82ee-303a64efb676"
```

**My next step**, is to create an `array` and `push unique strings` in it showing before **`'_'**` for each unique string showing right after **`'_'`**

So, with above data i should have two arrays. 1st array should contains `'5146d57a-701d-e511-82ee-303a64efb676_6544d57a'` and 2nd array `'5146d57a-701d-e511-82ee-303a64efb676_6544d57a'`

**My try:** (I am trying in the following way which actually far away from right implementation.)

```
int entityCount = model.Ids.Select(line => line.Split('_').Last()).Distinct().Count();
for (var i = 0; i < entityCount; i++) {
    string entityId = model.Ids.Select(line => line.Split('_').Last()).Distinct().FirstOrDefault();
    List<string> tstIds = model.Ids.Select(line => line.Split('_').First()).Distinct().ToList();
}
```

Kindly help me to resolve it.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Is this a case of "write my code for me", or is this a genuine homework problem?  Also, based on your sample strings, I don't see what your expected output is. Everything looks the same...

Comment: @ code4life, it is genuine problem im struck. It might be quick fix for you but for me it is an issue. thanks

Comment: OK. But I still honestly do not understand what you want done here. You want to push unique strings showing before `'_'` right after `'_'`... That's a contradiction. Show us the real example strings and the real expected output, it's so much easier that way.

Comment: @ code4life, i shortened my sample data. It may remove your confusion and you may be able to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
var entities = model.Ids.Select(line => line.Split('_').Last()).Distinct().ToList();
foreach(var entity in entities) {
    string entityId = entity;
    List<string> tstIds = new List<string>{entityId};
}
```

Get all distinct values and then add them to lists.